# Values-ldltr-v21.xml error + AAPT2 Error while trying to build in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Long story short, I'm a complete noob in android, bought an app code from codecanyon to use for my next project, I thought it was simple to use since I already did something similar a few weeks back. Anyway while trying to build/test run the app I get the following errors:

**C:\Users\username\Documents\MyApp\product\Project\proast\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml**

Error: file not found.

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
```

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

I have no idea what's going on and I tried searching and applying some of the methods I found online and on this site but I think I'm a complete idiot because I can't make it to work.

**Here's the build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**And the build.gradle (module app)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pro.ast"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

    //retrofit, gson
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.6.0'

    //glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'

    //circular imageview
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**I have android studio 3.0.1,
Android SDK installed: 27, 26, 25, 24, 23
java jdk: 1.8.0_144**

Any ideas? Would really appreciate it, I guess I will end up refunding the app code in the end since the seller is not responding yet.

Thanks in advance,
Stephen

Answer (score 4):

It is most likely related to AAPT2's limitation with paths on windows. It currently has issues with paths containing non-ascii characters and paths longer than circa 145 characters. 
This has been marked as fixed in the android issue tracker, but the fix hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Path length was my problem. I moved my project very close to the filesystem's root (think: `C:\temp-app\...` and it worked instantly.

Comment: I'm glad that worked out for you. :) The fix should be released soon so that you won't have to use these workarounds for much longer.

Comment: BTW the windows path issues were fixed starting android gradle plugin version 3.2.0-alpha11 (if I'm not mistaken), so if you use that version or newer there should be no more need for workarounds. :)